# Increasing the font size of first letter in UILabel.text

Tags: ios, uilabel

I would like the first letter of the UILabel to have a different font size from others, a few font size larger. Need some guidance on how to do it. The label has a lot of words.

This is what I have tried:

```
NSArray * words = [Label.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString *firstLetter = [[words objectAtIndex:0] substringToIndex:1];
```

But got stuck in increasing the size of the NSString. Is there a better way? I am welcome to suggestions and guidance.. Thanks..

EDIT:

```
[Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.f]];
NSArray * words = [Label.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
UIFont *fontFirst=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.f];
NSDictionary *attrsDictFirst=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *finalString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[[words objectAtIndex:0] substringToIndex:1]  attributes:attrsDictFirst];
```

Comment: If you only need iOS 6 or later then use `UILabel attributedText`. If you need to support iOS 5 or earlier then you can't have more than one font in a `UILabel`.

Comment: I suspect you have to use attributed text.  (Or split it into two labels.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get, for example, this:

[image]

Say this:

```
NSString* s2 = @"Fourscore and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth "
    @"upon this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated "
    @"to the proposition that all men are created equal.";
NSMutableAttributedString* content2 =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:s2
     attributes:
         @{
           NSFontAttributeName:
               [UIFont fontWithName:@"HoeflerText-Black" size:16]
         }];
[content2 setAttributes:
    @{
      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HoeflerText-Black" size:24]
     } range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
[content2 addAttributes:
    @{
      NSKernAttributeName:@-4
     } range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];

NSMutableParagraphStyle* para2 = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
para2.headIndent = 10;
para2.firstLineHeadIndent = 10;
para2.tailIndent = -10;
para2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
para2.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
para2.lineHeightMultiple = 1.2;
para2.hyphenationFactor = 1.0;
[content2 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                 value:para2 range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
```

Then assign `content2` to a label's `attributedText`.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the help. can explain what this line: NSKernAttributeName:@-4 does?

Comment: Otherwise the big letter is quite far from the small letter than follows it. This brings the bars of the "F" to overlap the "o".

Comment: Your answer is correct. Side question: I am adding a UILabel to a Scrollview, and I added your code. But it doesn't allow me to scroll. The words appear horizontally and do not appear vertically...

Comment: Did you set UILabel's number of lines to `0`? It won't wrap if you do not.

Comment: Code in my answer comes from here in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_attributed_strings

Comment: And here is the section on how labels work (can be a bit tricky): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_uilabel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28122/discussion-between-lakesh-and-matt)

Comment: 9000 should work. However this really is a completely new question; please ask a different question.

Comment: I typed in this: NSMutableAttributedString* content2 =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:s2
     attributes:
         @{
           NSFontAttributeName:
               [UIFont fontWithName:@"HoeflerText-Black" size:16]
         }];
[content2 setAttributes:
    @{
      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HoeflerText-Black" size:24]
     } range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
[content2 addAttributes:
    @{
      NSKernAttributeName:@-4
     } range:NSMakeRange(0,1)]; but it seems that my scrollview get pushed down after adding this line. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

Need to use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). **iOS6.0 onwards**

After getting the first letter make put it into attributed string, change its size.

take rest of the string set other size.

```
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.f];
NSDictionary *attrsDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attribString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[words[0] substringFromIndex:1]  attributes:attrsDict];


UIFont *fontFirst=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.f];
NSDictionary *attrsDictFirst=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *firstString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[attribString subStringToIndex:1]  attributes:attrsDictFirst];

[attribString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)  withString:firstString];
```

Comment: Remember, `UILabel` only supports attributed text in iOS 6.0 or later.

Comment: how to take the rest of the string?

Comment: once you get attribString, need to assign it back to label right?

Comment: @lakesh: I tried without compile check. Plz check and comment.

Comment: `myLabel.attributedText = finalString`

Comment: @lakesh: check my edit, if this doesn't work, try to appendString

Comment: @lakesh - in iOS 5, for a single-line label, I'd break it into two labels, use `sizeToFit` to make the first the right size, then snug the second label right up next to the first.  A multi-line label is probably impractical.

Comment: @lakesh - (The other obvious option is to simply not attempt anything fancy for iOS 5, and only do attributed strings for 6.)